# How do I access objects stored in COS (IBM Cloud) and display it to a webpage built in Django and deployed in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage, cloud-object-storage

I have a Django web app where I am showing videos. This web app is deployed using CloudFoundry. My videos are stored in a bucket in Object Storage of IBM Cloud. How do I access the objects so that the web page of my web app can directly show the videos? I don't want to enable public access on my bucket

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Static website hosting feature and don't turn on public access then authenticate to the s3-web endpoint in your Django app.
See this help topic
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-static-website-options